# How to delete all Azure emulator databases on local PC?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-sdk-.net

I'm new to Azure and .NET. I messed up a the database linked to a sample project. Now when I load a new version (of the same sample MVC web-app project) into VS2013, it points to the same old database on my PC (instead of creating a new one).

Where does VS2013 / Azure SDK emulator store local db instances so that I can delete them?

Comment: Perfect, this answers my question. However I'm only seeing 'system databases' under 'databases'. I think I might have deleted it from the SQLServer Project Explorer in VS2013. Now when I start a fresh version of the project, it doesn't make a new database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know that storage emulator uses `SQL Server LocalDB` for data storage by default and for each version of SDK a new database is created. What you can do is connect to `LocalDB` instance using `Sql Server Management Studio` as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Once you're connected, you will see all the databases (they would start with `WAStorageEmulator`). You can then delete the databases from there.

[image]

Comment: I could not find a WAStorageEmulator* database on my local SQL Server following a refresh of the database list. I suspect the storage implementation has changed since 2015.

Comment: @camelCase - That is correct. The old emulator is no longer in service and is replaced by [`Azurite`](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite). I believe the command you would need to use is `Azurite: Clean` to clean the database.